# Could not resolve property: name of: bookmarks.TagReference - Grails, Search

Tags: search, grails, tags, bookmarks

Good evening,
I'm creating a bookmark app from the book The Definitive Guide to Grails by Graeme Rocher. In this app I have 4 domains: User, Bookmark, Tag and TagReference. 
The Bookmark

```
hasMany = [tags:TagReference]
def belongsTo = User
User user   

URL url
String title
String notes
```

The TagReference

```
Bookmark bookmark
User user
Tag tag
```

The Tag

```
String name
```

I'm trying to search bookmarks not only by title and notes, but also by tags.

Bookmark Controller:

```
def search = {
    def criteria = Bookmark.createCriteria()
    def b = criteria.list {
                or {
                    ilike('title',"%${params.q}%".toString())
                    ilike('notes',"%${params.q}%".toString())

                    tags {
                        ilike('name',"%${params.q}%".toString())}
                    }
            }

           def fromDelicious = null
           try {
               fromDelicious = deliciousService.findRecent(session.user)
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
               log.error('Failed to invoke del.icio.us: ' + e.message, e)
           }
        render(view:'list',model:[bookmarkInstanceList:b.unique(),deliciousResults:fromDelicious])
```

/layouts/main

```
<g:form controller="bookmark" action="search" >
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" value="search" />
```

If I remove the **tags** part it works fine (only for searching by title and notes of course). But with it, I get this error:

```
Executing action [search] of controller [bookmarks.BookmarkController] caused exception: could not resolve property: name of: bookmarks.TagReference
```

I understand that's because my TagReference doesn't have the attribute name, but how can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your domain model you need to access the Tag.name property through the tags collection. So you criteria would look something like this:

```
def criteria = Bookmark.createCriteria()
def b = criteria.list {
            or {
                ilike('title',"%${params.q}%".toString())
                ilike('notes',"%${params.q}%".toString())

                tags {
                    tag {
                        ilike('name',"%${params.q}%".toString())}
                    }
                }
        }
```